# JQuery/ASP.Net Button Click Stops Working After Validate

Tags: jquery

This is the code in .cs code behind that gets injected into the page and the button markup in the ASCX that goes along with this code.

When the page is loaded, if I put in an email and click the button, my code behind is hit. If I leave the email field blank, the validation flags it as required (which is correct). If I then enter a value in the field and click the button again, my code behind does not get hit. This is very consistent in that if the validation marks the value as invalid, the button click will never get hit in the code behind.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnContinue" runat="server" onclick="btnContinue_Click" Text="Continue"/>


    @"$(document).ready(function() 
    {
       $('#" + this.btnContinue.ClientID + @"').click(function () {                 
          alert('In button continue click');             
       }); 

       $('#aspnetForm').validate({
          rules: 
          {" +
             this.txtEmail.UniqueID + @":
             {
                 required: true
             }
          }, 
          messages: 
          {" +
             this.txtEmail.UniqueID + @":
             {
                 required: 'Email is required.'
             }
          }
       });
    });";
```

---

I neglected to mention (it was a long, late night) this is happening in a webpart deplyed to SharePoint 2010. It turns out that our designer modified our master page which is causing the issue. If I use the default.master it works fine. I'm in the process of commenting out sections of the modified master page to find what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to verify the value of your button clientID  after validating the form, if it changes after click event fires, that's it.. Use $('#btn_continue') instead

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('#" + this.btnContinue.ClientID + @"').live('click', function () {                 
      alert('In button continue click');             
   });
```

That'll keep it working. When you reload after validation you are losing the binding to the element.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

If its an issue with the ID, you can add a class to it:

### Javascript

```
   $('.theButtonClass').live('click', function () {                 
      alert('In button continue click');             
   });
```

### ASPX

```
   <asp:Button ID="btnContinue" class="theButtonClass" runat="server" onclick="btnContinue_Click" Text="Continue"/>
```